# Do keys that are the same override each other in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Keys must be unique in a dictionary, but I typed in the following assignment statement and it worked:

```
test = {'A1': 12, 'A1': 13, 'A1': 14}
```

and then testing it, I found

```
test['A1']
14
```

My question is: will dictionaries with the same key repeated multiple times choose the last occurring instance of that key when called? (i.e. Do the entries override each other)

Comment: Yep, dict and set in Python both doesn't allow duplicate keys.

Comment: Yes, the last key/value added will be what you see

Answer (score 2):

In Python, Dictionary storage is very interesting. Internally dictionaries are implemented using hash tables. So when you initialise a dictionary , these are the following steps that takes place in the background:

- Internally PyDict_New() is called.
- Allocation of new object
- Few steps for getting available slots
- While adding a new key/value pair it first searches for existing hash for the key. If it finds then use the same hash. So if you search for duplicate key , it fetches the lastest one.

Nice explanation for Python dictionary implementation http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/