# Is a dict literal containing repeated keys well-defined?

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

If I write `d = {0: 1, 0: 2}`, does Python guarantee the value of `d[0]`, or is it "undefined behavior"?

(Of course, this isn't something you'd *ever* write when programming, but this question is mostly out of curiosity. Locally, it seems to always save the value associated with the key's last occurrence, i.e. `2` here. Maybe it's useful info for some weird code gen situations, though.)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I don't see the question about *literals* and whether they are *"well-defined"* specifically in [your duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503527/do-keys-that-are-the-same-override-each-other-in-a-dictionary-in-python).

Comment: The word "literal" isn't in that question's title, but the body is almost identical except for different variable names.

Comment: I am not asking **if** the keys override. I am asking if it's defined **how** that happens. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Re. your last sentence, I found this construct useful when I wanted all the keys and an arbitrary value for each key, though it was a comprehension rather than a literal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, it is well-defined -- last value wins. `{0: 1, 0: 2}` is a [dictionary display](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

> If a comma-separated sequence of key/datum pairs is given, they are
>   evaluated **from left to right** to define the entries of the dictionary:
>   each key object is used as a key into the dictionary to store the
>   corresponding datum. This means that you can specify the same key
>   multiple times in the key/datum list, and **the final dictionary’s value
>   for that key will be the last one given**.<sup>emphasis is mine</sup>

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I don't consider it a duplicate.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: holy wars were started for less (literal holy wars e.g., [two fingers vs. three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raskol)). It is not about how close are the words (questions may be duplicates even if they are formulated completely differently at a glance). It is about the **intent**. The other question wouldn't change if the dictionary were created dynamically (as I understand it).

Comment: Thank you for the reference!

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {0: 1, 0: 2}
a[0]
2
```

It will give the value of highest index in the same or duplicate key's value